# Javascript prevent out function call

Tags: javascript

```js
function alertOuter() {
  alert("outer alert")
}

function alertInner() {
  alert("inner alert")
  return
}
```

```html
<div onclick="alertOuter()" style="padding:20px;background:red;">
  <h1>Outer</h1>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="alertInner()">Inner</button>
</div>
```

I have two function calls on `onclick` event.

I want to prevent `alertOuter` function when clicking on the button.
But, it is calling both the functions when i am clicking on the button.

I wants to prevent that `alertOuter` funcion when clicking on the button just wants to call `alertInner()` function

How can I do that?

Comment: `stopPropogation()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach the event listener properly using Javascript so you can see the event parameter, and then call `stopPropagation()` on the event, so it doesn't bubble up to the containing `<div>`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('inner');
});
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('outer');
});
```

```html
<div style="padding:20px;background:red;">
  <h1>Outer</h1>
  <br/>
  <button>Inner</button>
</div>
```

Best to [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have confusing behavior, require global pollution, and are pretty much never required.

Answer (score 1):

I usually like using inline `onclick` calls as you've done. I find it easier and cleaner to keep track of, and I don't have any issue with it. Here's how you'd use `stopPropagation` that that way:

```css
div{
  background:red;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="alert('outer');">
  <button onclick="event.stopPropagation();alert('inner');">Click me for inner</button>
</div>
```